# An example of a non-abelian group of order $p^3$

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be prime and consider the set of all matrices $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z_p}$. This set forms a non-abelian group of order $p^3$.

Any ideas how to prove using group actions?

Comment: Aren't you overthinking this?  Do you have a doubt about it being a group?  About being nonabelian?  Or about it having order $p^3$?

Comment: It is the [discrete Heisenberg group modulo p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Discrete_Heisenberg_group)

Comment: @hardmath Maybe I was. The answer below is straight forward. The section I am working on involves group actions so I thought proving this would require such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-a&ac-b\\0&1&-c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Use the two-step group test to show that it is a group.

For the non-abelian part pick two matrices such as
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$
and show that they does not commute.

The order part should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

$${{H}_{p}}=\left\{ \left. \left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a & b  \\
   1 & 1 & c  \\
   1 & 1 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\,\, \right|\,\,\,a,b,c\in {{Z}_{{{p}^{3}}}} \right\}
$$
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a & b  \\
   0 & 1 & c  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a' & b'  \\
   0 & 1 & c  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix}' \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a+a' & b+b'+ac'  \\
   0 & 1 & c+c'  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\ne \left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a+a' & b+b'+a'c  \\
   0 & 1 & c+c'  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a & b  \\
   0 & 1 & c  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a & b  \\
   0 & 1 & c  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a & b  \\
   0 & 1 & c  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
$${{\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & a & b  \\
   0 & 1 & c  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}^{-1}}=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & -a & ac-b  \\
   0 & 1 & -c  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

---

let 
$$G=\left\{ \left. \left( \begin{matrix}
   x & y  \\
   0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\, \right|\,\,x,y\in {{Z}_{{{p}^{2}}}}\,,\,\,x=1\,\,\bmod \,p\, \right\}
$$Indeed we can say $H_p$ and $G$ are isomorphic!

Comment: This last statement is interesting. How is it relevant to the question asked?

Comment: so it is not relevant, but we can use $G$ instead of $H_p$. I think it is so better.